# Azure Batch - Upgrade to the latest API version

Tags: azure, azure-batch

I have some jobs running under an Azure Batch and I received a warning saying I must upgrade the API verion.
Where should I do that?

The current version I'm using will be removed on 10/31/2020

[image: Bath API version Warning]

Edit:
I accessed my batch and then the Job Schedules:
[image: Job Schedules]

These are the properties of one of those jobs:
[image]

Should I configure the api-version here?

Comment: in your job declaration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely, you are utilizing Batch through an SDK, Azure CLI, Powershell, or Batch Explorer. Each of these ultimately call the Batch service through a REST API which is versioned. You need to ensure that you are not using a deprecated version of such SDKs or tooling.

Please see [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/rest/api/batchservice/batch-api-status) for more information for associated SDK versions for deprecated REST API versions.

Comment: I found an app using the Azure.Batch nuget, wich was replaced by Microsoft.Azure.Batch.

The following link helped me in the migration: 
https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/blob/master/sdk/batch/Microsoft.Azure.Batch/CHANGELOG.md

Thanks fpark